# inserting query_string into an array as key => value

Tags: php, arrays, query-string

ı have a query_string and ı want to use it in array.

ı have found this way by myself but its just a little complicated ı am searching new way.

```
function query_to_array($query){


$pieces = explode("&", $dizi);

$seri=array();
$seri_two=array();

for ($i=0;$i<count($pieces);$i++)
{
$seri = explode("=", $pieces[$i]);
$seri_dizi[$seri[0]]=$seri[1];
}

return $seri_dizi;
}
```

this works great but ı need another way.

Comment: You don't need to define `$seri` outside of the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you try to access your GET or POST data (in your query). If so you just have to use the global variable $_GET['paramname'] for GET data or $_POST['paramname'] for post data.

Edit: I may have misundertood your question, you work with arbitrary request string, not the request to your page right? If so Pekka gave the rigth function to use.

Regards